# How to keep the innerhtml content that is changed with the JS onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is a simple problem but cant seem to solve it.
I want to be able to change the innerhtml content of a link, once is triggered by an onclick function triggered from separate link that actually takes the user to another page (inside the website not external site), I get the script to work but the desirred innerhtml content to be changed dissapears once the page reloads and goes to the other page the link is pointing to. I actually want to keep the change of the text change even if the page is reloaded and taken elsewhere.

The script looks like something like this:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("testchange").innerHTML = "Get Started";
    } //Js script that does the innerHMTL change
</script> 

<a href="http://example.com/en/page.html"  class="lang-col" onclick=" myFunction()">eng</a> // button that triggers the onclick function but takes the user to another page inside the site

<a href="http://example.com" id="testchange" >Hello</a> // text to be changed by JS and want to keep the change even if the page is reloaded and taken elsewhere
```

So any ideas how i could do that? Thanx

Comment: If the page reloads the current page, and JS execution context, also goes away. You could do something like use local storage, but... it sounds more like you need to be doing something on the server side, or doing a real single-page app.

Comment: Thanx for the feedback, what you say makes sense, hopefully someone can help me out on how to solve this. thanx

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you want cannot be done with pure JS. You could have it send you to a modification of the link (not sure exactly how) and in the onload javascript, it checks modifications to the url. If modification is say "http://example.com/en/page.html?myFunction" then it will run myFunction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work you need some kind of storage. Let's try localStorage:

You first check if the changes has been made before setting the variable, then handle your event:

```
<script>
    function ready(fn) {
        if (document.readyState != 'loading'){
            fn();
          } else {
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
          }
        }
    }

    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("testchange").innerHTML = "Get Started";
        //this will save the state of the change
        localStorage.setItem('textSet', true);
    }

    //this will change the text when the page is loaded if the change has been made before.
    ready(function(){
        if(localStorage.getItem('textSet')){
            document.getElementById("testchange").innerHTML = "Get Started";
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: This is the follow up question to this answer, hopefully you guys can help me again on that, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32447508/how-to-trigger-a-js-script-only-after-a-specific-function-is-called  Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Either use Cookies or Session/Local storage, sessionStorage option below

Data stored in sessionStorage will lasts as long as the browser window is open, whereas localStorage has no expiration time

```
<a href="http://example.com/en/page.html"  class="lang-col" onclick=" setFlag()">eng</a>
<a href="http://example.com" id="testchange" >Hello</a>
<script>
    function setFlag() {
      sessionStorage.setItem('setFlag', 'true');
    } 
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("setFlag")) 
        document.getElementById("testchange").innerHTML = "Get Started";
</script>
```

Note: this code will need to be place after your HTML elements ideally at bottom of the page

Comment: You've got unbalanced curly brackets

Comment: Thanx, actually there are some brackets missing and tried the script in diffrent ways but didnt work, thanx anyways, the correct script is below!! Thanx again for helping out!