# How to trigger a JS script only after a specific function is called

Tags: javascript, jquery

basically this it a follow up of this question, 
[How to keep the innerhtml content that is changed with the JS onclick function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429487/how-to-keep-the-innerhtml-content-that-is-changed-with-the-js-onclick-function/32429556#32429556)

So i got that local storage question right (that was the deal on the previous question), now i need to trigger this script which translates an innerhtml text to Hungarian and i all create different version of this script for different languages:

```
 ready(function(){
        if(localStorage.getItem('textSet')){
            document.getElementById("testchange").innerHTML = "Hungarian Lang"; //this part will change depending on language translations
        }
    })
```

The script above is triggered by this one (the one below) in this case the Hungarian function since its translating a text to that language, cause its for translation purposes, so the script below is for hungarian or function hungarianlang1(){ } so i all have this same script for italian or function italianlang1(){ } and have its translation script (the 1st script) called.

```
function hungarianlang1() {
            document.getElementById("testchange").innerHTML = "Hungarian Call"; 
            //this will save the state of the change
            localStorage.setItem('textSet', true);
        }
```

So i want to have a conditional statement,  that triggers the 1st script depending on which language function is called (the 2nd function), how would that conditional look like, any ideas.
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your first function is malformed? Are you trying to call a function called `ready`?

If you're using jQuery, the proper way to set a callback for when the DOM is ready is like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // your code here
});
```

Or you can use the shorthand:

```
$(function() {
  // your code here
});
```